# certain parameter should be attached on every return by controller using model in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model, return-value

### I am using spring MVC with Hibernate

My Query is that when a `Controller` return some data to a view using `Model`, as defined below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/finGeneralJournalAdd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String finGeneralJournalAdd(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("srcDocumentList", pt.getAll(FinSourceDocumentModel.class));
    model.addAttribute("currencyList", pt.getAll(GenCurrencyModel.class));
    model.addAttribute("batchList", pt.getAll(FinBatchModel.class));

    return "fin/finGeneralJournalAdd";
}
```

Certain parameters should be attached to `Model` by default on every return.**i.e CurrencyId**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, that's exactly what `@ModelAttribute` is for ([docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)). You add a method to the controller that is called everytime before a handler method is called. The return value is added to the model.

```
@ModelAttribute("currencyId")
public Integer currencyId(...) {
    ...
    return currencyId;
}
```

If that should happen for every controller you can define it in an `@ControllerAdvice`-annotated class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `postHandle` method of a Spring `HandlerInterceptor`.

See this blog http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/ for an example of how to implement a HandlerInterceptor